# laravel5.3 incorrect format of URL when getting from database

Tags: json, url, return, laravel-5.3

I save URLs inside my database.
They are saved correctly, for example this URL is saved inside the db.

```
http://xy.com/raw/mhhxKh7Q
```

Now when I try to use this for a JSON based API:

```
         return response()->json([
                'url'  => $merchant->url
            ]);
```

I get something like this:

```
http:\/xy.com\/raw\/mhhxKh7Q
```

How to fix this?

Comment: How are you getting the information? I.e. Ajax, Postman, another php app etc?